# Как вставить шорт-код из contact form 7 в javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Подскажите как вставить  шорт-код из contact form 7  в файл JavaScript?
Сайт на WordPress, хочу из Contact Form 7, вставить шорт-код в JavaScript файл.
Вставить его нужно в модальное окно которое динамично генерируется на JavaScript.

Вот пример кода только нужно шорт-код как то обернуть

```
<p class="modal__order__text">${this.name}, ${this.year}р,<br>${this.size}. ${this.materials}</p>
        
      
    [contact-form-7 id="211" title="Форма Замовлення"]
       
              
<p class="modal__gallery__price order__price">Ціна: ${this.price}$</p>
```

Comment: Шорткод не отработает в JS файле и выведется просто как текст.

Comment: То есть никак не вставить?

Comment: Ну конкретно вставить шорткод можно, но вам нужно скорее не вставить сам шорткод, потому что толку от этого не будет, а вставить HTML формы, которая выводится при помощи этого шорткода.

Comment: Не совсем понял, имеете в виду просто версткой вставать форму?

Comment: Чтобы на фронтенде вывелась контактная форма, нужно чтобы шорткод был обработан, обработан он может быть только на стороне сервера, потому он и не будет работать у Вас в JS файле. Обработка шорткода происходит при помощи ф-ции [do_shortcode()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/do_shortcode).

Comment: А в файл Js можна вставить немного кода php обернуть шорт-код в функцию  do_shortcode(). Cделать запрос на сервер из файла JS?

P.S. Я так пробовал делать у меня не получилось, но может я сделав что-то не так

Comment: Не совсем понял. Но в таком случае Вам проще будет получить эту форму аяксом. Либо вы могли бы добавить форму в какой-то скрытый контейнер в футере и например вырезать ее и вставить в Ваше модальное окно, когда оно вызывается.

Comment: Понял, Спасибо)))